# Авторизация на сайте onlinebanking.mtb.com с помощью requests

Tags: python-3.x, requests

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте, но не выходит.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url_login = r'https://onlinebanking.mtb.com/Login/MTBSignOn'

r = requests.get(url_login, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('Login', 'Pass'))
```

Возникает такая ошибка:

> Internal Server Error
>
> ## Internal Server Error - Read
>
> The server encountered an
>   internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your
>   request.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Также я пытался сделать так:

```
payload = {
    'UserId': 'Login',
    'Passcode': 'Pass',
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'onlinebanking.mtb.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://onlinebanking.mtb.com/Login/MTBSignOn',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

r = requests.post(url_login, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Но авторизация не проходит.

Comment: А во втором случае какая ошибка происходит?

Comment: Метод get надо использовать и куки вставлять и ещё вы бы в ЦРУ таким способом попробовали авторизоваться

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы посылаете запрос без куков. Вам нужно сначала зайти на страницу входа, сохранить переданные куки, и затем уже отправить запрос на вход с сохранёнными куками. Для этой задачи проще всего будет [использовать объект сессии](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects).

То, что куки нужны, легко увидеть в инструментах разработчика.

[image: Стрелка указывает на заголовок Cookie]

Необходимые параметры кроме логина и пароля вы можете подсмотреть там же.